# Getting currently clicked layer from MapLayerTable

Tags: layers, geotools

I've added a `MapLayerTable` to my application, and I'm loading multiple layers using shape files successfully. Now I would like to select features on the map of the selected layer. For this, I would need to find the currently clicked layer.

I've already used the following code to check whether the layers are active and selected.

```js
for (Layer layer : mapPane.getMapContent().layers()) {
    if (layer.isSelected()) {
        System.out.println("Layer selected : " + layer.getTitle());
    }
}
```

But what I need is a method to select only one layer. E.g.: clicked layer, right clicked layer. I hope there would be a method to select one layer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `MapLayerTable` allows you to select 0 to many layers there is no way to have a `getSelected()` method easily implemented. But when you select a layer in the table it calls `setSelected` on the layer which fires a `MapLayerEvent.SELECTIONCHANGED` event to any `MapLayerListeners` that are registered. So you can maintain your own list of selected layers that is updated via the `MapLayerTable`.